# Symbol 'is_integral' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I tried to solve a C++ symbol problem but I could not find a solution:

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;


/*
 * static_assert(constant-expression, error-message): static_assert provides compile-time asserts.
 * type traits: characteristics checked at compile-time
 */


template<class T>

T bitwise_and(T x, T y) {
     static_assert(is_integral<T>::value, "bitwise_and parameters must be of integral type");
     return x % y;
}

int main() {

     //1. Basic static_assert example
     static_assert(sizeof(long) == 8 , "32 bit required");

     //2. calling a generic function that enforces type rules with static_assert
     unsigned int x = 122127, y = 10;
     int r = bitwise_and(x, y);
     cout << r << endl;

     unsigned char c = 10, d = 2;
     int r1 = bitwise_and(c, d);
     cout << r1 << endl;

     // assert is not valid
     //double w = 1, z = 10;
     //int r2 = bitwise_and(w, z);

     cout << "End" << endl; // prints
     return 0;
}
```

I have added the option -std=c++11 to eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) like this:

[eclipse c++11 setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO5Bu.jpg)

but its not working

I have tried -std=c++14, its not working too any idea ?

**my c++11 setting is working for other new language features**

Note: the code in running fine under visual studio 2015 community edition

here is the errors after build:

[errors output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh7b8.jpg)

gcc:
gcc version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6) (GCC)

thanks.

Comment: Why does `bitwise_and` use `%` instead of `&`?

Comment: What version of GCC you're using?

Comment: I'm using gcc 5.3.1 on fedora

Comment: What's the exact error message? Copy and paste the full compiler output.

Comment: Does it work if you compile it manually with something like `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11`?

Comment: the output errors are added

Comment: command line test as: g++ -std=c++11 moveSemantics.cpp, is working but not in eclipse

Comment: So the problem is obvious and should lead to the compiler settings in eclipse. But I would not put it in the command field.